How to simplify function with multiple if-statements and multiple conditions?
I have a function which should output which test scores are significantly higher than the other test scores. There are four tests (a, b, c and d). The user will input the test scores and check different checkbuttons if there are significant differences between any of the test scores. There are 6 checkbuttons in total: "a & b", "a & c", "a & d" and so on. The user will have access to all this info beforehand.
The Problem
My current function works, but in order to cover every eventuality I would have to write out many, many if-statements:
def my_function (A_test_score, B_test_score, C_test_score, D_test_score, A_B_state, A_C_state, A_D_state, B_C_state, B_D_state, C_D_state):
 
    A_test_score = int(a.get())
    B_test_score = int(b.get())
    C_test_score = int(c.get())
    D_test_score = int(d.get())
 
    # Retrieving state of the checkboxes (1 = checked)
    A_B_state = A_B_var.get()
    A_C_state = A_C_var.get()
    A_D_state = A_D_var.get()
    B_C_state = B_C_var.get()
    B_D_state = B_D_var.get()
    C_D_state = C_D_var.get()
 
    final_text = ""
 
    if A_B_state == 1:
        if (A_test_score - B_test_score) > 0:
            final_text += "A is significantly larger than B"
        elif (A_test_score - B_test_score) < 0:
            final_text += "B is significantly larger than A"
 
    if A_C_state == 1:
        if (A_test_score - C_test_score) > 0:
            final_text += "\nA is significantly larger than C"
        elif (A_test_score - C_test_score) < 0:
            final_text += "\nC is significantly larger than A"
 
… # and so on…
 
    if A_B_state == 1 and (A_test_score - B_test_score) > 0 and A_C_state == 1 and (A_test_score - C_test_score) > 0 and A_D_state == 1 and (A_test_score - D_test_score) > 0:
        return "A is significantly larger than B, C and D"
 
    if A_B_state == 1 and (A_test_score - B_test_score) > 0 and A_C_state == 1 and (A_test_score - C_test_score) > 0:
        return "A is significantly larger than B and C"
 
    return final_text

Disered Output
If for example the score on test a and b are significantly larger than c and d:
"a and b are significantly larger than c and d."
And if, for example, a is larger than b, c and d, and b is larger than d:
"a is significantly larger than b, c and d.
b is larger than d."
Thus, the goal is to avoid redundant outputs like this:
"a is significantly larger than b.
a is significantly larger than c.
a is significantly larger than d."
I'm guessing there is a better way to to this... Can't find anything in the previous suggested posts so far. Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Use sequence types (e.g. list, dict) instead of a sequence of variables.

Thanks for your reply. Could you perhaps illustrate how to do this using a small example? I’m familiar with lists and dicts, but not for this use.

Well, Stack Overflow is not a tutorial. You will actually have to learn a language if you want to program in it. And list and dictionaries are two very basic and important things to know in Python.

Fair enough. However, I would say that the leap from a basic understanding of dictionaries and lists to a solution like the one presented by @acw1668 may not be intuitive for everyone. But I could be wrong.

You can use a list result_a to store items that is less than A.  Same for B, C and D.  Then you can use these lists to construct the final text:
def my_function():
    A_test_score = int(a.get())
    B_test_score = int(b.get())
    C_test_score = int(c.get())
    D_test_score = int(d.get())
 
    # Retrieving state of the checkboxes (1 = checked)
    A_B_state = A_B_var.get()
    A_C_state = A_C_var.get()
    A_D_state = A_D_var.get()
    B_C_state = B_C_var.get()
    B_D_state = B_D_var.get()
    C_D_state = C_D_var.get()

    # lists to store checking result
    result_a = []
    result_b = []
    result_c = []
    result_d = []

    if A_B_state:
        if A_test_score > B_test_score:
            result_a.append("B")
        elif B_test_score > A_test_score:
            result_b.append("A")

    if A_C_state:
        if A_test_score > C_test_score:
            result_a.append("C")
        elif C_test_score > A_test_score:
            result_c.append("A")

    if A_D_state:
        if A_test_score > D_test_score:
            result_a.append("D")
        elif D_test_score > A_test_score:
            result_d.append("A")

    if B_C_state:
        if B_test_score > C_test_score:
            result_b.append("C")
        elif C_test_score > B_test_score:
            result_c.append("B")

    if B_D_state:
        if B_test_score > D_test_score:
            result_b.append("D")
        elif D_test_score > B_test_score:
            result_d.append("B")

    if C_D_state:
        if C_test_score > D_test_score:
            result_c.append("D")
        elif D_test_score > C_test_score:
            result_d.append("C")

    # list to construct the final text
    final_result = []

    if result_a:
        final_result.append(f"A is significantly larger than {' and '.join(result_a)}")

    if result_b:
        final_result.append(f"B is significantly larger than {' and '.join(result_b)}")

    if result_c:
        final_result.append(f"C is significantly larger than {' and '.join(result_c)}")

    if result_d:
        final_result.append(f"D is significantly larger than {' and '.join(result_d)}")

    # return the final text
    return "\n".join(final_result)


Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for. Worked like a charm. Very elegant (and instructive).

First of all, you should always place you "data validation conditions" at the begining of methods. What I mean by "data validation conditions" is conditions you check to be able to correctly run whatever the method needs to run.
For example:
# in an imaginary case where 9 is not a number you want to compute
def add_but_not_nine(a, b):
    result = a + b
    if a == 9 or b == 9:
        return "can't compute nines"
    return result

Is not very readable, whereas:
# in an imaginary case where 9 is not a number you want to compute
def add_but_not_nine(a, b):
    if a == 9 or b == 9:
        return "can't compute nines"
    return a + b

This is better. This isn't a good example but I hope it gets the message across.
So in your case, you should change your code to this:
def my_function (A_test_score, B_test_score, C_test_score, D_test_score, A_B_state, A_C_state, A_D_state, B_C_state, B_D_state, C_D_state):
 
    A_test_score = int(a.get())
    B_test_score = int(b.get())
    C_test_score = int(c.get())
    D_test_score = int(d.get())
 
    # Retrieving state of the checkboxes (1 = checked)
    A_B_state = A_B_var.get()
    A_C_state = A_C_var.get()
    A_D_state = A_D_var.get()
    B_C_state = B_C_var.get()
    B_D_state = B_D_var.get()
    C_D_state = C_D_var.get()
    if A_B_state == 1 and (A_test_score - B_test_score) > 0 and A_C_state == 1 and (A_test_score - C_test_score) > 0 and A_D_state == 1 and (A_test_score - D_test_score) > 0:
        return "A is significantly larger than B, C and D"
 
    if A_B_state == 1 and (A_test_score - B_test_score) > 0 and A_C_state == 1 and (A_test_score - C_test_score) > 0:
        return "A is significantly larger than B and C"
    final_text = ""
 
    if A_B_state == 1:
        if (A_test_score - B_test_score) > 0:
            final_text += "A is significantly larger than B"
        elif (A_test_score - B_test_score) < 0:
            final_text += "B is significantly larger than A"
 
    if A_C_state == 1:
        if (A_test_score - C_test_score) > 0:
            final_text += "\nA is significantly larger than C"
        elif (A_test_score - C_test_score) < 0:
            final_text += "\nC is significantly larger than A"
 
… # and so on…
 
    
 
    return final_text

I recon you can make other improvements, but that's what really stands out to me.
